# Login page and NavBar formatted with Reactstrap (Vertical and with custom background and text color)

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, reactstrap

I'm trying to make a login page , which would let me access me to the main site with displays a NavBar. I'm using ReactStrap, and I can't find the way of making the NavBar vertical instead of horizontal, neither setting the background and text colours and images. I could achieve to make a conditional rendering (to let administrator users to access some funcionalities like adding products, other users, and make puchrases, while sellers users are only allowed to make sales and view the sales registers).

Here's my code:

App.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import "./bootstrap.app.css";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route} from "react-router-dom";

import Example from "./componentes/navbar.componente"
import RegistroVentas from "./componentes/registro-ventas.componente";
import EditarVenta from "./componentes/editar-venta.componente";
import VenderProducto from "./componentes/realizar-venta.componente";
import NuevoUsuario from "./componentes/nuevo-usuario.componente";
import NuevoProducto from "./componentes/nuevo-producto.componente";
import ComprarProducto from "./componentes/realizar-compra.componente";

function App() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div className="container">
      <Example />
      <br/>
        <Route path="/" exact component={RegistroVentas} />
        <Route path="/registroVentas" component={RegistroVentas} />
        <Route path="/editar/:id" component={EditarVenta} />
        <Route path="/venta" component={VenderProducto} />
        <Route path="/nuevoUsuario" component={NuevoUsuario} />
        <Route path="/nuevoProducto" component={NuevoProducto} />
        <Route path="/compra" component={ComprarProducto} />
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;
```

navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react';
import {
  Collapse,
  Navbar,
  NavbarToggler,
  NavbarBrand,
  Nav,
  Badge,
  NavItem,
  NavLink,
  UncontrolledDropdown,
  DropdownToggle,
  DropdownMenu,
  DropdownItem } from 'reactstrap';
//import FontAwesome from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';

//import 'Ventas' from './ventas-cod'

class Ventas extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(
        <NavItem>                
          <NavLink href="/venta">
            <Badge pill color="dark">Venta</Badge>
          </NavLink>
        </NavItem>
      );
  }
}

class Compra extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return(

              <NavItem>
                <NavLink href="/compra">
                  <Badge pill color="dark">Compra</Badge>
                </NavLink>
              </NavItem>
      );
  }
}

class Altas extends React.Component {
  render () {
    return(  
              <UncontrolledDropdown nav inNavbar>
                <DropdownToggle nav caret>
                  <Badge pill color="dark">Altas</Badge>
                </DropdownToggle>
                <DropdownMenu right>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    <NavLink href="/nuevoUsuario">
                      <Badge pill color="dark">Usuario</Badge>
                    </NavLink>
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem>
                    <NavLink href="/nuevoProducto">
                    <Badge pill color="dark">Producto</Badge>
                    </NavLink>
                  </DropdownItem>
                  <DropdownItem divider />
                  <DropdownItem>
                    Reset
                  </DropdownItem>
                </DropdownMenu>
              </UncontrolledDropdown>
      );
  }
}


export default class Example extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.tipoUsuario='administrador';
    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
    this.state = {
      isOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      isOpen: !this.state.isOpen
    });
  }

  render() {
    
    return (
            
      <div>
        <Navbar  color="green"  expand="lg">
          <NavbarBrand  href="/">Supermercado Caplan</NavbarBrand>
          <NavbarToggler vertical className="d-flex" onClick={this.toggle} />
          <Collapse isOpen={this.state.isOpen} navbar>
            <Nav className="d-flex ml-auto" >
              <Ventas />
              {this.tipoUsuario=='administrador' ?      
                <Compra /> : <a></a>
                }
                {this.tipoUsuario=='administrador' ? 
                <Altas /> : <a></a>
                }
            </Nav>
          </Collapse>
        </Navbar>
      </div>lt
    );
  }
}
```

Here's what I'm getting:[image: result]

Here's something I would like to get:[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what should I do?

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0):

In Reactstrap, there's no such a thing like a native component called Sidebar.
However, it's possible to download a template with a sidebar implemented, and then wrap the whole application into it.
For the login cuestion, there's a lot of examples on the web. While all of them should work correctly if implemented properly, I've chosen one of the simplest I found, which works fine for the kind of project I'm doing. However, while it allows me to login with my credentials into a local deployment, it isn't probably the best solution for an application deployed into a web service, since the security of the system it's not just a big deal for an app which is running into a local machine, just written for academic purposes.
So then, here's the template I've found for the Reactstrap sidebar and the login method in which I've based on to implement in my app, and also my app with both things implemented.

Sidebar template:
https://codesandbox.io/s/5ku6t

Login method used:
https://contactmentor.com/login-form-react-js-code/

App with login and sidebar implemented:
https://gitlab.com/leandrocaplan/supermercado-caplan-final-programacion-iii-inspt-utn
(See the frontend folder to see the implementation)

Notice that in my app, the way I've found to format the sidebar, and also the topbar, is creating my own CSS classes, and apply them into the sidebar and topbar components. These classes are found in the App.css file at the correspondent frontend directory.